# gatsbyjs: using graphql multiple times, or one time and pass the results through context?

Tags: gatsby, graphql-js

Using `gatsby-node.js` and creating pages programatically, I have 2 options:

1. I can do a graphql query on `gatsby-node.js` of everything I need, and then pass the (e.g.) array of edges with `context` to the different templates I use.

This way, the template won't need to do another `graphql` query again

2. I can do the same query on `gatsby-node.js` (because I need the information anyway), but then I can just pass with `context` the relevant info to the templates, so that they can do other `graphql` queries to retrieve the data they need.

This way, I don't pass tons of data through context (it's not the case, but this could happen eventually), but instead I repeat the database queries.

What is more efficient? I see that the docs seem to suggest to repeat `graphql` queries, but I'm not completely sure.

So the question is, **is there any drawback in doing a bunch of calls to `graphql` in gatsby? Or it is preferred to do one call and use javascript for the rest?**

(example)

```
export const createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
...
  return graphql(`
    query {
...
  `).then(result => {
...
     result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.map(({ node }) => {
      createPage({
        component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/myTemplate.js`),
        context: {
          name: node.name,
          title: node.title,
          date: node.date,
          tags: node.tags,
          html: node.html,
        },
...
```

and in the template, don't do any query since the needed content is in the context

Or the opposite

```
      createPage({
        component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/myTemplate.js`),
        context: {
          name: node.name,
        },
```

and in the template, do the specific query

```
  query($name: String) {
    allMarkdownRemark(filter: { name: {eq: $name }}) {
      edges {
        node {
          name
          title
          date
          tags
          html
        }
      }
    }
```

**In my eyes**, doing these 2 queries seems redundant, but then, it could be that overusing `context` is detrimental somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, there's this [gatsby issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/6467#issuecomment-405613559)

> But really full data shouldn't be passed by context to page - you should only pass minimal needed data ( like ids or slugs) to be used in page queries to get full data there.

I think your example data is minimal enough that it doesn't matter, though I do want to add that creating queries for each templates has a few perks:

- How the data is queried is put right next to its component - no going back and forth between `gatsby-node.js` and template when something needs debugging.
- Adding data is easier since you only need to modify the query (vs modifying the query & then add data to context)

Comment: Yes, these are excellent points, more modularity indeed, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I've decided to leave the minimum possible query in `gatsby-node.js` and that every template carries out their queries better suited for what they need